# Breaking Down a String into Maximum Character Sections in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I need to break apart strings in JavaScript into chunks of no greater than 100 characters while maintaining breaks between words. I have a function in my own personal library for chunkifying a string into 100-character sections, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to adapt it to avoid splitting in the middle of a word. I figure something can be managed using regular expressions or something, but it just isn't coming to me. One caveat to any solution is that it has to be pure JavaScript, no jQuery, and the environment has no access to browser-related globals.

**-- EDIT --**

Ok, I've written some code, but I'm getting strange results...

```
function chunkify(str) {
    var wsRegEx = /\S/;
    var wsEndRegEx = /\s$/;
    var wsStartRegEx = /^\s/;
    var chunks = new Array();
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = 100;
    var totalChar = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (totalChar >= str.length) break;
        var chunk = str.substr(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex);
        while (wsStartRegEx.test(chunk)) {
            startIndex++;
            endIndex++;
            totalChar++;
            chunk = str.substr(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex);
        }
        if (!wsEndRegEx.test(chunk)) {
            while (wsRegEx.test(chunk.charAt(endIndex))) {
                endIndex--;
            }
            chunk = str.substr(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex);
        }
        chunks.push(chunk);
        totalChar += chunk.length;
        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += 100;
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

A previous version I posted wasn't counting chunks correctly, but this version, which does seem to break correctly, is now breaking mid word.

**-- EDIT #2 --**

I think I got it working great now. This seems to do the trick:

```
function chunkify(str) {
    var wsRegEx = /\S/;
    var chunks = new Array();
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = 100;
    while (startIndex < str.length) {
        while (wsRegEx.test(str.charAt(endIndex))) {
            endIndex--;
        }
        if (!wsRegEx.test(str.charAt(startIndex)))
            startIndex++;
        chunks.push(str.substr(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += 100;
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, or have I gotten this to be about as efficient as it'll get?

Comment: What all have you tried so far? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to spec this out for you, so you understand one way it can be done

```
function chunkify (str) {
  var chunks = [];
  var startIdx = 0, endIdx;
  //Traverse through the string, 100 characters at a go
  //If the character in the string after the next 100 (str.charAt(x)) is not a whitespace char, try the previous character(s) until a whitespace character is found.
  //Split on the whitespace character and add it to chunks
  return chunks
}
```

Comment: Would this essentially be handled within a do/while loop?

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley possibly. You will need to use a looping mechanism, of which there are several in javascript and jquery

Comment: Can't use jQuery, not available in the work environment. It almost seems like this might be most likely a pair of nested loops. One loop to handle the overall structure, and an inner loop to slide backwards along the string to find the last whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with regex:

```
chunks = str.match(/.{1,100}/g);
```